# Pycharm venv packages not available to me?

Tags: python, pycharm

I just created a pycharm virtual enviorment, and would like to use some specific packages inside of it. It's these two cryptography ones:

[image]

But when I try to import them in my code, the import doesnt complain, but when I try to acces the library, no suggestions are given.
What should I do in order to actually use a library?

[image]

Comment: in some libraries you may want import specific objects. try `from crypto import (whenever you need)` and then you use. P.S - you use suggestions in pycharm, use Ctrl+Space

Comment: Please don't provide screenshots but rather text whenever possible.  Also, if you do have to enter images, there should be a way to cause them to be displayed inline in your question.  I've never done that myself, but I've seen it done by others.

Comment: Make sure that you've set your virtualenv as the Project Interpreter in your current project. (Settings -> Project: project name -> Project Interpreter)

Comment: Marc, i'm not really sure what you mean? just that I should set my Interpreter to be my python installation? that is what I have done noe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `crypto`, but its top-level `__init__.py` contains nothing and hence there is nothing to suggest.

You'll receive completion with non-empty modules, e.g.:

```
import crypto.library.hash

crypto.library.hash.<here>

# or

from crypto.library import hash

hash.<here>
```